# KMM Multiplatform Project won't run on IOS

Tags: android, ios, xcode, kotlin-multiplatform

I have built a Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile application, which runs on Android, but when I try to build the project on IOS device, I am facing the following error:

1. Compilation failed: Server returned HTTP response code: 416 for URL: https://download.jetbrains.com/kotlin/native/apple-llvm-20200714-macos-aarch64-essentials.tar.gz
2. org.jetbrains.kotlin.konan.util.DependencyDownloader$HTTPResponseException: Server returned HTTP response code: 416 for URL: https://download.jetbrains.com/kotlin/native/apple-llvm-20200714-macos-aarch64-essentials.tar.gz

[image: Xcode Compilation Error]

I have built the project on KOtlin, there is a seperate IOS portion on the project, I open the KmpApp.xcworkspace on Xcode, and run build. but I am getting the compile error.

Comment: I would try again. I was able to get the file from that link. Also, what version of kotlin are you running?

Comment: I am also able to download directly from the link.
I am using kotlin version of 1.9.21

Comment: I was also able to run the app on a different mac, is this problem my device oriented? I am confused, what should I do next?

Comment: That's hard to say. I'd probably try deleting the ~/.konan folder, maybe Gradle cache folders as well, then build again. That doesn't seem likely to be the issue, though.